# Want to pass parameters to SSIS through sql server procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 
'DTExec /f "Abc\demo\demo\package.dtsx" 
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::ServerName].Value";"\\ABZ"
/SET "\Package.Variables[Package::id].Properties[Value]";"\\1"'
```

Till i hardcode value It is running(upto ABZ).But when i want to pass value, code runs but value is not passing in ssis package?Please rectify my code

Comment: If you're trying to set connection details at runtime use `configurations` instead.

Answer (score 0):

create a job, with sql agent, and add the parameter in the parameter tab, and after you can copy the correct exec-string.

 howewer the parameter string looks like
`/SET "\Package.Variables[User::log].Properties[Value]";`

you can see this link
http://jeffprom.com/2010/08/30/passing-parameters-into-ssis-from-a-sql-job/

something like this

```
   EXEC xp_cmdshell 
    'DTExec /f "Abc\demo\demo\package.dtsx" 
    /SET "\Package.Variables[User::ServerName].Properties[Value]";"\\ABZ"
    /SET "\Package.Variables[Package::id].Properties[Value]";"\\1"'
```